# How to calc the logged in user of past 7 days when having the login record in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I have a dataframe like this:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
l = []
for day in range(30):
    for userid in range(random.randint(5,30)):
        l.append([day,userid])
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['Day','UserID'])
```

I want to know **the unique user count** of logged in users in the past 7 days. And I'm now using code like this:

```
result = {}
df.set_index('Day',inplace=True)
for d in df.index.unique():
    result[d] = df[(df.index>=d-6) & (df.index<=d)].count()
pd.DataFrame(result).T
```

but I think my code sucks. Could you please help show me a more elegant way to do this? Such as pandas.rolling_sum or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

You were correct: rolling_sum is the way. The way I would approach it, eventhough it isn't one-liner:

```
# Generate random log data 'your' way
import random
import pandas as pd
l = []
for day in range(30):
    for userid in range(random.randint(5,30)):
        l.append([day,userid])
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['Day','UserID'])

# Calculate desired statistics
df = df.groupby("Day").count() #calculate daily log count (this command will make a Day colum your index by default too)
df.columns = ["Daily count"] #rename column to make it more meaningful
df["Weekly count"]=pd.rolling_sum(df["Daily count"],window=7,min_periods=1) #calculate weekly count of previous column
```

That would produce your desired result:

```
     Daily count  Weekly count
Day                           
0             16          16.0
1             13          29.0
2             19          48.0
3              8          56.0
4             22          78.0
5             21          99.0
6             18         117.0
7              7         108.0
8             12         107.0
9              7          95.0
10            17         104.0
11            21         103.0
12            22         104.0
13            20         106.0
14            19         118.0
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it seems that you missed one point: if a userid 39 logged in for day 1 and day 2, you would count him twice, but we should just count him one time.